# exercise 2.10 in silverman AEC

Tags: elliptic-curves

the exercise 2.10(a) in silverman AEC says $(\phi_*f)(D)=f(\phi^*D)$.(any $f\in \bar K \ (C_1),D\in Div(C_2) )  
( \phi:C_1 \rightarrow C_2 is \ a \ nonconstant \ map \ of\ smooth\ curve $  )

(Here we need the support of divisor D and the support of div(f) disjoint)

I want to prove the simple case. When $D$ is $Q(Q \;\text{is a point in}  \ C_2$).

Then we need prove 
$$N_{K(C_1)/\phi^* K(C_2))}(f)(\phi^{-1}(Q))=\prod_{P\in\phi^{-1}(Q)}f(P)^{e_{\phi}(P)}$$
For  $$N_{K(C_1)/\phi^* K(C_2))}(f)=\prod_{\sigma\in Gal({K(C_1)/\phi^* K(C_2))}}\sigma(f)$$,
then i want to prove $\sigma(f)(P)=f(P_1) (some\ P_1\ is \ in \ \phi^{-1}(Q))$

and it is true for all Q in $C_2$.

Then i guess $Gal({K(C_1)/\phi^* K(C_2)})$ may have action on $\phi^{-1}(Q)$,
$Gal({K(C_1)/\phi^* K(C_2)}) \times\phi^{-1}(Q)\rightarrow\phi^{-1} Q)$,$(\sigma,P)\rightarrow \sigma (P)$
which keeps $\sigma(f)(P)=f(\sigma (P)) $.

Then we can prove $N_{K(C_1)/\phi^* K(C_2))}(f)(\phi^{-1}(Q))=\prod_{P\in\phi^{-1}(Q)}f(P)^{e_{\phi}(P)}$.

But i don't know whether it is true. Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: It might help your cause to explain what $D$, $f$, $\phi_*$, and $\phi^*$ mean. True, many of the people who can help you will have access to Silverman's book, but not all. Or, their copy may be in their office, but now it's weekend. I can guess that $D$ may be a divisor, $\phi$ a map between two curves, but what is $f$? Edit the question body, please. The goal is to make the question as self-contained as possible.

Comment: Sorry, I edit the question and give the mean of D,f,$\phi$.

Comment: I have written a solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157977/norm-map-on-function-fields-of-curves/4451177#4451177)