# Norm map on function fields of curves

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

For a curve $C$, $f\in \bar{K}(C)^*$ and a divisor $D = \sum n_P(P) \in \text{Div}(C)$ such that $D$ and $\text{div}(f)$ have disjoint supports (support of a divisor is the set of points with non-zero coefficients in its sum), we define :
$$f(D) = \prod_{P\in C}f(P)^{n_P}$$

Let $\phi:C_1\rightarrow C_2$ be a non-constant map of smooth curves. Then show that $f(\phi^*D) = (\phi_*f)(D)$ for all $f\in \bar{K}(C_1)^*$ and all $D\in \text{Div}(C_2)$ whenever both sides are defined. Here, $\phi^*:\bar{K}(C_2)\rightarrow \bar{K}(C_1)$ is the induced map on function fields and $\phi_*:\bar{K}(C_1)\rightarrow\bar{K}(C_2)$ is the map defined as $$\phi_* = (\phi^*)^{-1}\circ N_{\bar{K}(C_1)/\phi^*\bar{K}(C_2)}$$
where $N$ denotes the usual norm of field extensions. This is question 2.10(a) from Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves. So far, I have managed to reduce it to the case where $\phi$ is separable, but I don't understand how to proceed further, since I don't really have a good understanding of what the norm map does in this context. I would prefer if the solution uses only the algebraic geometry discussed so far in Silverman.

This question has been asked before at [exercise 2.10 in silverman AEC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2735515/exercise-2-10-in-silverman-aec), but it received no responses.

Comment: For $P \in C_1,Q=\phi(P)\in C_2, f(X) \in k(C_1), g(X) = N_{k(C_1)/\phi^* k(C_2)}(f(X))$ you want to show $g(P) = \prod_{R\in \phi^{-1}(Q)} f(R)^{e(R)}$ where $e(R)$ is the ramification index defined by $e(R)=ord_R h(\phi(X))$ for $h(Y) \in k(C_2)$ with a simple zero at $Q$. If $k(C_1)/\phi^* k(C_2)$ is a normal extension this is easy because $N_{k(C_1)/\phi^* k(C_2)}(f(X)) = (\prod_{j=1}^n f(\psi_j(X)))^d$ where $f(X) \mapsto f(\psi_j(X))$ are the automorphisms $\in Aut(k(C_1)/\phi^* k(C_2))$ and $n = [k(C_1):\phi^* k(C_2)]_s$ and $d =[k(C_1):\phi^*k(C_2)]_i=\frac{[k(C_1):\phi^* k(C_2)]}{n}$.

Comment: The $\psi_j$ are some birational maps $C_1 \to C_1$ such that $\phi( \psi_j(X))=\phi(X)$, equality of rational maps so there are a few problematic points at the poles of the $\psi_j$. Now if $k(C_1)/\phi^* k(C_2)$ is not a normal extension (for example in the elliptic curve/isogeny case) then the $\psi_j$ are replaced by the embeddings from $k(C_1)$ to $L$ the normal closure of $k(C_1)/\phi^* k(C_2)$ and I'm not sure how to deal with it.

Comment: Even in the case when $k(C_1)/\phi^*k(C_2)$  is a normal extension, I don't see why the ramification indices should appear in the product expression for the norm.

Comment: Let $u(X)$ with a unique zero of order $l$ at $P$ then $N_{k(C_1)/\phi^* k(C_2)}(u(X)) = (\prod_j u(\psi_j(X))^d=v(X)=w(\phi(X))$ where the zeros of $v(X)$ are at the $R \in \phi^{-1}(\phi(P)$ so $w(Y)$ has a unique zero of order $m$ at $\phi(P)$. If necessary replace $u(X)$ by $1/(1/u(X)+c)$ so there is no cancellation in the zeros/poles of the $u(\psi_j(X))$ so that $l = m$ obtaining $e(R) /d$ is the number of $\psi_j$ sending $P$ to $R$

Comment: Thanks! I don't really see what to do in case of a non-normal extension either. Assuming a result from Hartshorne, that given any finitely generated field of trancendence degree one over $k$ is a function field of some curve, using that on the normal closure of the extension $k(C_1)/\phi^*k(C_2)$ and that $N_{K/M} = N_{L/M}\circ N_{K/L}$, I found that $f(\phi^*D)^d = ((\phi_*f)(D))^d$, where $d = [K:k(C_1)]_s$ and $K$ is the normal closure of $k(C_1)/\phi^*k(C_2)$, but I am not sure how to get rid of the exponent.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove this for the case $D=(Q)$ where $Q$ is a point of $C_2$. Let $A$ be the image of the local ring of $C_2$ at $Q$ under the map $\phi^*$ (i.e. it is a discrete valuation ring of $\phi^*K(C_2)$). Let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $K(C_1)$. Write $m_Q$ for the maximal ideal of $A$. Then $m_Q$ splits in $B$ into the product $\prod_{\phi(P)=Q}m_P^{e_\phi(P)}$ where we similarly write $m_P$ for the maximal ideal of $B$ corresponding to a point $P$ lying over $Q$.
We can identify the value $\phi_*f(D)$ with the image of $N_{B/A}(f)$ in $A/m_Q=\overline K$ (note that $f\in B$ as the supports of $\operatorname{div}f$ and $\phi^*D$ are disjoint by assumption)
Now we have the following commutative diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
B @>>> B/m_QB;\\
@V{N_{B/A}}VV @V{N_{(B/m_QB)/(A/m_Q)}}VV \\
A @>>> A/m_Q
\end{CD}$$
Denote by $\bar{f}$ the image of $f$ in $B/m_QB$. Since $B/m_QB$ splits as $\prod_{\phi(P)=Q} B/m_P^{e_\phi(P)}$, hence $$N_{(B/m_QB)/(A/m_Q)}(\bar{f})=\prod_{\phi(P)=Q}N_{(B/m_P^{e_\phi(P)})/(A/m_Q)}(\bar f).$$
Writing $f=f(P)+ g$ where $g(P)=0$ we see that the map given by multiplication by $\bar{f}$ in $B/m_P^{e_\phi(P)}$ is $f(P)\operatorname{id}+N$ where $N$ is nilpotent. It is easy to see that then $\det(f(P)\operatorname{id}+N)=\det(f(P)\operatorname{id})$ (e.g. by writing $N=M^{-1}\tilde{N}M$ where $N$ is upper triangular with zeros on the diagonal). Hence $N_{(B/m_P^{e_\phi(P)})/(A/m_Q)}(\bar f)=f(P)^{e_{\phi}(P)}$ and we get \begin{align*}
f(\phi^*D):=\prod_{\phi(P)=Q}f(P)^{e_{\phi}(P)}&=\prod_{\phi(P)=Q}N_{(B/m_P^{e_\phi(P)})/(A/m_Q)}(\bar f)\\&=N_{(B/m_QB)/(A/m_Q)}(\bar{f})
=\overline{N_{B/A}(f)}=(\phi_*f)(Q)
\end{align*}